# Tutorial how to create Photoshop Action

Tags: adobe-photoshop, actions

I want to understand how photoshop action is being made to get a result like this:

[image]

It can be a different effect but with a similar style, idea on how it's being made. There is full youtube with videos how to apply these actions, but very limited info on how actually they are step-by-step made. Can someone help with this?

I want to make actions on my own, but when I went trough all the layers for already made and applied action, there was a lot of questions. For example, one question of them - before action is being played, the areas where to apply the effect needs to be brushed on new layer with specific name and then run the action and it applies to this zone. What's the idea for this and how I can make action with this function?

Answer (score 0):

Actions can only perform tasks. What the painting is doing is creating a Layer. Without seeing the action what I would imagine its going to do is use that Layer (or that Layer's channel) to create various layer masks. That's a pretty clever workaround really but to create an action to not even need to do that would be nearly impossible as every image differs.

The only way I'd see that being possible is if you had an Action for say Black Background and an action White Background and only run it on things with isolated subjects on those backgrounds.